# Why isn't SDL2 able to load my .bmp in Xcode? (SDL_LoadBMP)

Tags: c, xcode, sdl, sdl-2, bmp

I am trying to load a .bmp file into my SDL project in Xcode through the SDL_LoadBMP function.
I have tried placing the file to be loaded in the project debug folder and tried entering the full search path, none of them have worked. By Using SDL_GetError I get the message "Couldn't open ‎⁨⁨hello_world.bmp".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(){

    SDL_LoadBMP("‎⁨⁨hello_world.bmp");
    printf("%s\n", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Failure to open probably indicates that the file is not found, but might indicate that the program does not have the permissions needed to read the file.  Start by going back to opening the file via its full path (and verify that path).  If that does not resolve the issue then check you privileges on the file by opening it in some other image viewer.

Answer (score 0):

After verification the SDL2 display the message `"Couldn't open %s", filename` if the cpp function `fopen` or `fopen_s` return `nullptr` but SDL2 didn't display/use the errno set by fopen.
**So we can guess that you didn't set the correct path for the bmp file**, the path need either relative to the executable or absolute.

Comment: When I use the SDL image library I can load the files with the same path. Maybe it has something to do with Mac not being able to load .bmp files?

Comment: I still think the issue is directly linked to the path you entered because internally the function `IMG_Load()` of the SDL_Image use the function `SDL_RWop()` (the same function used in `SDL_LoadBMP()`) this is written in the [official documentation](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html#SEC10).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error message "Couldn't open x.bmp". **Here's what worked for me and what I wish I had found straight away (using SDL2 and Xcode 12):**

The directory where the `.bmp` files have to be saved for `SDL_LoadBMP()` to work (at least for me) is:

```
/Sunday3/DerivedData/Sunday3/Build/Products/Debug/Sunday3.app/Contents/Resources
```

and **NOT** in the same directory as the `.exe` file, which is in:

```
/Sunday3/DerivedData/Sunday3/Build/Products/Debug/Sunday3.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Both locations start at the project root, and not the PC root.

I troubleshooted the issue by using `fopen` and by putting the `.txt` files in the same directory as the `.exe` (as you'd do normally) and, as expected, they did not open.